# SQL Server Memory Usage Increases Over Time

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have written a C# windows service that collects syslog and inserts them to a SQL server database.

Average insert range is 5-10 inserts Per Second and each time I have a read operation and an insert operation.

I should note that I use the "Using" command for managing SQL server connections.

The only problem I face is that memory usage of windows increases steadily and even reaches to 6GB!
Is this a normal case?
and if it is what's the solution to decrease memory usage?

Comment: Sql Server likes a lot of memory. You can [set the maximum memory Sql Server is allowed to use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx) but recommended for development only, not in production.

Answer (score 0):

> The only problem I face is that memory usage of windows increases steadily and even reaches to 6GB! Is this a normal case?

This is normal ,until you face issues with memory pressure..

How to identify and troubleshoot, if you have memory pressure..?

How SQLserver manages memory is a complex topic,but there are many [links in SO](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%20memory%20pressure%20site%3A*.stackexchange.com) which will help you

> and if it is what's the solution to decrease memory usage?

Its Good to follow best practices and leave 10% to OS and leave the rest to SQLServer by setting max memory limit

Comment: Is it efficient to use bulk insert rather than using a stored procedure? (by Inserting Values to datatable and bulkinsert to database)